# how to find if a table is being read or written in a procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table named 'abc_tbl' and i want to know if it is being read (SELECT) or written (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) in a list of 100 procedures which are using this table.

Comment: I want to categorize these procedures on the basis of whether they read/write from/to the table

Answer (score 1):

You can use `information_schema.routines` to find procedures referencing your table `abc_tbl`.

The `SQL_DATA_ACCESS` column will return one of the following values:

1. NONE
2. CONTAINS
3. READS
4. MODIFIES

[Link to MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188757.aspx)

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.routines ISR
WHERE CHARINDEX('<your_schema_name>.abc_tbl', ISR.ROUTINE_DEFINITION) > 0
GO
```

Comment: i have already obtained the dependency. Wanted to know how to categorize as read/write.

Comment: Updated answer as per comment @Ankita

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.name AS ObjectName,
CASE o.xtype
WHEN 'C' THEN 'CHECK constraint'
WHEN 'D' THEN 'Default or DEFAULT constraint'
WHEN 'F' THEN  'FOREIGN KEY constraint'
WHEN 'FN' THEN 'Scalar function'
WHEN 'IF' THEN 'In-lined table-function'
WHEN 'K' THEN 'PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint'
WHEN 'L' THEN 'Log'
WHEN 'P' THEN 'Stored procedure'
WHEN 'R' THEN 'Rule'
WHEN 'RF' THEN 'Replication filter stored procedure'
WHEN 'S' THEN 'System table'
WHEN 'TF' THEN 'Table function'
WHEN 'TR' THEN 'Trigger'
WHEN 'U' THEN 'User table'
WHEN 'V' THEN 'View'
WHEN 'X' THEN 'Extended stored procedure'
ELSE o.xtype
END AS ObjectType,
ISNULL( p.Name, '[db]') AS Location
FROM syscomments c
INNER JOIN sysobjects o ON c.id=o.id
LEFT JOIN sysobjects p ON o.Parent_obj=p.id
WHERE c.text LIKE '%table_name%'
ORDER BY Location, ObjectName
```

Comment: this will not tell me whether the procs read/write to/from the table

Comment: In a procedure we can do all the things like we can insert, update and delete. So It would be difficult to define as far as I knew.